# ruby on rails inline error validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery

im trying to use ajax forms witin a modal window to allow my users to edit/create new objects, the issues im having is that the errors arent being displayed.

in my controller i have the following

```
 def create
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @players = User.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id]).all
    #params[:event][:datetime] = "#{params[:event][:date]} #{params[:event][:time]}"
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        #Notifier.event_added(@event,@user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to(events_url,
                                  :notice => "#{event_display_c(@event.event)} vs #{@event.opponent.name} was successfully created.") }
        format.js { @events = Event.all }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.js { render :json => @event.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

in my create.js.erb i have

$("#events_list").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render('events_list') %>");

and in my partial i have

```
 - if @event.errors.any?
  .alert-box.error
    %a.close{:href => ''} ×
    %strong Error:
    = pluralize(@event.errors.count, 'error')
    prohibited event from being saved:
    %ul
      - @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
%h5 Schedule Form
= form_for(@event, :html => { :class => "custom"}, :remote => true, :validate => true) do |f|
  .row
    .two.columns
      = f.label :event_type, :class =>'control-label'
    .four.columns
      = f.select :event, Event::EVENT_TYPES
    -if current_user.admin?
      .two.columns
        = f.label :team, :class =>'control-label'
      .four.columns
        = select("event", "team_id", Team.all.collect { |p| [truncate(p.name, :length => 18, :omission => '...'), p.id] }, {:prompt => 'Select a team'})
    - else
      =f.hidden_field :team_id, :value => current_user.team_id
  .row
    .two.columns
      = f.label :name, :class =>'control-label'
    .ten.columns
      = f.text_field :result_id, :class => "required"
  .row
    .two.columns
      = f.label :date_and_time, :class =>'control-label'
    .ten.columns
      .input-prepend
        %span.add-on
          %i.icon-schedule
      = f.text_field :time, :id => 'datepicker', :class => "hasDatepicker", "data-date-format" => "dd/mm/yyyy"
  .row
    .two.columns
      = f.label :duration, :class =>'control-label'
    .four.columns
      = f.number_field :duration, :placeholder => 'Time in Minutes'
    .two.columns
      = f.label :arrival_time, :class =>'control-label'
    .four.columns
      = f.number_field :arrival_time, :placeholder => 'Time in Minutes'
  .row
    .two.columns
      = f.label :location, :class =>'control-label'
    .four.columns
      = select("event", "location_id", Location.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'})
    .two.columns
      = f.label :opponent, :class =>'control-label'
    .four.columns
      = select("event", "opponent_id", Opponent.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'})
  .row
    .two.columns
      = f.label :players, :class =>'control-label'
    .four.columns
      = select(:event, :selected_players, @players.map { |p| [full_name(p), p.id] }, {:include_blank => false}, "data-placeholder" => 'Add Players to Lineup', :prompt => 'Add Players to Lineup', :multiple => "multiple", "data-customforms"=>"disabled")
    .two.columns
      = f.label :home_or_away, :class =>'control-label'
    .four.columns
      = f.select :home_or_away, Event::HOME_OR_AWAY, {:include_blank => 'None'}
  .row
    .two.columns
      = f.label :scores, :class =>'control-label'
    .three.columns
      = f.number_field :score_for, :placeholder => 'Our Score'
    .two.columns
      %label vs.
    .three.columns
      = f.number_field :score_against, :placeholder => 'Opponents Score'
  .row
    = f.submit :class => 'button success', :disable_with => "Saving Event..."
    = link_to 'Cancel', 'javascript:void(0);', :class => 'button alert close-reveal-modal'
```

what the console is outputting

```
   Started POST "/events" for 168.186.239.50 at 2013-02-08 06:59:47 +0100
Processing by EventsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CBiKEQN+Q2Dkhgt7MSJbjU7WzuUPgW0/z6m71KdDpnU=", "event"=>{"event"=>"1", "team_id"=>"", "time"=>"", "duration"=>"", "arrival_time"=>"", "location_id"=>"", "opponent_id"=>"", "selected_players"=>[""], "home_or_away"=>"", "score_for"=>"", "score_against"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 38 LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 38]]
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."team_id" = 1
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  Event Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" 
  Rendered events/_events_list.html.haml (1.1ms)
  Rendered events/create.js.erb (3.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 516ms (Views: 13.3ms | ActiveRecord: 17.5ms)
```

Comment: can you try including the `#event_list` div on the partial?

Comment: i would have thought as i have `if @event.errors.any?` in my form it would have routed the errors, the event_list is just a table of all the events

Comment: yep but you are using `replaceWIth` which replaces the div with the partial.  the next time you do submit the form, `#event_list` won't be there anymore.

Comment: oh and just found out that you're using `render :json` inside `format.js` so `create.js.erb` will not be rendered

Comment: so do i need to ignore that render within format.js?

Comment: yep just put in `format.js`. that should render the file.

Comment: i changed it to `format.js { render :js => @event.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }` but still didnt get the errors :s

Comment: ah no, remove the block so the line only has `format.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `respond_to` block to

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @event.save
    #Notifier.event_added(@event,@user).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to(events_url,
                              :notice => "#{event_display_c(@event.event)} vs #{@event.opponent.name} was successfully created.") }
    format.js { @events = Event.all }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.js
  end
end
```

and change `create.js.erb` to

```
`$("#events_list").html("<%= escape_javascript render('events_list') %>")`
```

since you don't have the `#events_list` div on that partial

Comment: changed to the above, still errors arent being rendered :S im getting this in the console `Rendered events/create.js.erb (6.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 68ms`

Comment: look at the stack trace on the development log, you'll see the error there.

Comment: okay so ive checked error log and fixed the missing class, but its still not rendering any errors :s

Comment: then check the response of the ajax. try to manually run the javascript generated and see if there are errors.

Comment: added in what im seeing in the console, doesnt appear to be any reason why it would be working. this one really has me stumped

Comment: no i mean in the js console.  there's probably some js errors which prevented the html to update.  try adding a `console.log` line at the bottom of `create.js.erb` and see if you see that in the js console.

Comment: i tried to get too clever and thought id need to ajax called the notice, which was causing the issues. thanks your code above works :)

Comment: if i wanted to call this function within my create.js.erb only if i get no errors how would this be achieved `$('#newEvent').trigger('reveal:close');`

Comment: try <%= "$('#newEvent').trigger('reveal:close');" if @event.errors.empty? %>